# python seleniumでjavascriptボタンを押す方法がわからない

Tags: python3, google-chrome, jupyter-notebook, selenium

#### 前提・実現したいこと

python seleniumでjavascriptボタンを押す方法がわからないです。
直接ボタンを押すことで一端は解決したのですが、異なるPCで使うとクリックするボタン位置が変わるので直接要素を押せる様にしたいです。

```
#直接ボタン位置を指定してクリック
import pyautogui as pg
pg.click(x=350, y=530, button='left')
```

分かる方教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)
```

#### 入手したいソースコード

```html
<div class="modal-footer"><a data-handler="0" class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:;">すぐにダウンロード</a>
<a data-handler="1" class="btn btn-large btn-warning" href="javascript:;">件数を確認後にダウンロード</a>
<a data-handler="2" class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:;">キャンセル</a></div>
```

#### 試したこと

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn-success').click()
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Python 3.7.3
Windows7
jupyter notebook
chromedriver

Comment: これを試してみるとか。[seleniumでスクレイピング--click()でエラーが発生する](https://teratail.com/questions/115570)

Comment: 自己解決しました。
<a data-handler="0" class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:;">となっていましたので、「class name」で要素取得できないのは、javascriptだからだと思ってしまっていましたが、「xpath」で要素取得できました。

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div[3]/a[1]').click()