# VBA Selenium ChromeDriver Webメールに添付ファイルを付けたい

Tags: google-chrome, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

roundcube webmail で vba selenium chromedriver を使用してメール作成、送信を試みています。
タイトル、本文などは入れられたのですが、添付ファイルを設定する方法がどうしてもわかりません。ご存じの方、ご教授お願いします。

```
  With CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")

    .Start
    .Get "https://roundcube.xxx.ne.jp/"

    '検索するキーワードを投入
    .findelementbyID("rcmloginuser").SendKeys "testuser@ne.jp"
    .findelementbyID("rcmloginpwd").SendKeys "testpwd"
    .findelementbyID("rcmloginsubmit").Click

    .Wait (2000)
    .findelementbyID("rcmbtn107").Click
    .Wait (2000)

    .findelementbyID("_to").SendKeys "testuser@aaa.co.jp"

    .findelementbyID("compose-subject").SendKeys "testMailSubject"

    .findelementbyID("composebody").SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value

    .findelementbyID("attachment-list").Sendkeys "C:/aaa/bbb/myfile.txt"
    ※ここでつまずく

  end with
```

Comment: このページ [Roundcube 基本操作 メールの作成/返信/転送](https://zenlogic.jp/support/knowledge/roundcube/mail_send.html) に「ファイルを添付する場合は「ファイルを添付」ボタンをクリックし、ファイルを選択します。」とありますけど、その「ボタンをクリック」してファイルダイアログの方への入力が必要とか？

Comment: はい。ファイルダイアログが出てきて選択したファイルを添付できる仕組みです。JavaScript を呼び出しているようなのですが、受け渡し方法が分からないです。

Comment: 関連するファイルダイアログ項目のウインドウハンドルを探して、それに入力するという方法があるようです。そのものズバリでは無いですが、この辺の記事から読み解いてみてください。pythonの記事 [Seleniumのsend_keys()を使わずにファイルをアップロードする](https://rmc-8.com/programming/python/selenium-fileupload), [seleniumとpywinautoでChromeのWEBページを印刷する。](https://ohtorii.hatenadiary.jp/entry/20171029/p1) IE?とVBAの記事 [VBAでファイル選択ダイアログを自動操作する](https://rabbitfoot.xyz/file-dialog-autmation/) こちらは出来なかったという記事 [VBA IE制御でファイル選択ダイアログにファイルパス入力](https://teratail.com/questions/62945)

Comment: ボタンをクリックするのは(pythonですが)この記事とかでしょうか。[python seleniumでjavascriptボタンを押す方法がわからない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/61675/26370)